# Why does Rust not infer the right type for a closure passed to filter?

Tags: rust, closures, type-inference

If I have the following code:

```
let a = 1;
let f = |n| n == &a;
let _: Vec<_> = (1u64..10).filter(f).collect();
```

Rust complains greatly that `collect` exists for the relevant `Filter` struct, but the trait bound `FnMut` is not satisfied by the closure.

However, if I inline the closure or annotate its argument type, the code works, such as:

```
let a = 1;
let _: Vec<_> = (1u64..10).filter(|n| n == &a).collect();
```

or:

```
let a = 1;
let f = |n: &u64| n == &a;
let _: Vec<_> = (1u64..10).filter(f).collect();
```

Why is this?  The fact that inlining the closure without annotating the type works is truly bizarre.  I would think it was because `n` was having its type inferred as `u64` instead of `&u64` because ranges have some kind of propensity towards getting consumed but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact rule, but from what I've observed working with Rust, creating a closure without requiring a specific type *always* causes the type to be inferred from the information available in the *declaration of the closure* only — not how the closure value is used later. That is, Rust's type inference stops being “bidirectional” in this case. For example:

```rust
let f = |x| x.clone();
f("hello world");
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:11:14
   |
11 |     let f = |x| x.clone();
   |              ^ consider giving this closure parameter a type
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point
```

This example fails to compile because the compiler does not use the information from the *call* to `f` to decide that `x` should be `&str`.

In your case, I'm not sure exactly what the problem is.

- I'd assume it was a lifetime problem (the parameter lifetime being inferred as the lifetime of the borrowed `a` rather than an arbitrary lifetime) but then I would think that `|n: &u64|` wouldn't help.
- Another hypothesis is that the problem is that the `==` operator is a `PartialEq::eq` call in disguise, and it isn't inferring what the `Self` type of that call is (since some type other than `u64` *could* implement `PartialEq<&u64>`. But then I'd expect to see another “type annotations needed” error, requiring you to narrow down which trait implementation is to be used.

I don't have a precise explanation, but generally you should expect that when you separate a closure's definition from its usage, you are likely to need to add more type annotations.